# AlwaysOn Availability Group and workgroup servers

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2016, high-availability

Has anyone had any luck setting up AGs with servers in a workgroup, neither server in a domain (no domain even exists for this client). I've added DNS suffix to both servers, like recommended. I have both servers using matching local service accounts for SQL, share that is accessible by both servers. When adding the Secondary Replica, I select SQL Authentication instead of Windows. I've blown away the Endpoints and recreated (several times). Nothing in the SQL or Windows logs either.

ServerA.local.workgroup
ServerB.local.workgroup

[image]

Comment: Do you have Windows Firewall turned on?

Comment: Is endpoint created and started ? That could be the problem in joining the AG.

Comment: Try the excellent checklist from Guy Glantser: http://www.madeiradata.com/availability-group-sql-server-2016/ It's way harder than it looks.

Comment: sp_BlitzErik,  Windows firewall has been turned off and the firewall is wide open while we test and configure.

Comment: Kin, the endpoint was successfully created and started.

Comment: Brent Ozar, thanks for the link, checking it now. I am now seeing that it's not exactly as simple as if the servers were in a domain.